# must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function for count postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

```
select count(*) from CustomerOrder co where  
 co.createdAt >= :fromDate and co.createdAt <= :toDate order by co.createdAt desc;
```

I have above count HQl query while I executing I'm getting GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: I suspect it complained about the createdAt field in the error? Remove the order by clause it has no influence on the result anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  aggregations  functions are not affected by order clause  so you obtain the correct result without adding an order by.
you can't    a selected  column not mentioned  in group by and not involved in aggregation. In your case the order by createdAt   work as  the createdAt  is  selected and  this raise the error

so if you want the count for your where condition you just need

```
select count(*) 
from CustomerOrder co 
where  co.createdAt >= :fromDate and co.createdAt <= :toDate
```

otherwise if you want an aggregated  result for each createdAt  then you must add
this column the a group by clause

```
select createdAt , count(*) 
from CustomerOrder co 
where  co.createdAt >= :fromDate and co.createdAt <= :toDate 
GROUP BY createdAt
```

in this case you obtain one row for each createdAt  with the proper count

Comment: Maybe `count(*)`  should also be replaced by `count(co)` , as this is HQL